# i am using ContactsContract is shows error that mean it creates another class

Tags: android

How can I get phone numbers, email_ids and names from contact list

when I am using ContactsContract it shows error how can I avoid those problems so anyone

Comment: please post the code you're using as well as the error you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you are missing permission. Check this [Android Contacts Api](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html)